# Bootstrap 4: trying to align content inside a card to the bottom right

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align my text and button inside a card to the bottom right but I can't get them to align properly.

[image]

This is my code:

```
<div class="col-sm-3  text-right my-auto">
  <div class="card text-white text-right d-flex">
    <img src="images\col_img_2.jpeg" class="card-img" alt="...">
    <div class="card-img-overlay justify-items-end d-flex align-items-end">
      <h5 class="card-title">Project 2</h5>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Lees verder</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this?
Thank you for your kindness in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I fixed it by using mt-auto on the 'h5' element!
This pushes the 'h5' element and 'a' element to the bottom of the card.

```
<div class="col-sm-3  text-right my-auto">
  <div class="card text-white text-right d-flex">
   <img src="images\col_img_2.jpeg" class="card-img" alt="...">
    <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex align-items-end flex-column">
      <h5 class="card-title mt-auto">Project 2</h5>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Lees verder</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```